# Saving and retrieving from NSArray using NSUserDefaults - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I've been trying to save an array into NSUserDefaults and retrieve it to second array but it gives me cast exception.

I'm saving my array of strings like this:

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array[indexPath.row], forKey: "Array")
```

And retrieving into the second array :

```
 var second : NSArray!

        if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Array") != nil){
            second  =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Array")! as! NSArray
            println("\(second.count)")
        }
```

It gives me this error :

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x19871b958) to 'NSArray' (0x19871c308).
```

I am just trying to store the first array into the second array when retrieving it as String array.and why I'm using `indexPath.row` because i am storing item each time in the array. not the whole array at same time. like i am updating the array repeatedly.

Comment: You store an String instead of Array.

Comment: @NekakKinich, but i need to store each time one item to an array ? its not possible ?

Comment: You can store all the array, but if you store repeatedly "Array", only overwrite the same key.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't storing the array, you're storing one item from the array, which happens to be a string. This is because you are storing `array[indexPath.row]` instead of just `array`.

Change to:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array, forKey: "Array")
```

Comment: im storing specific item from row, in the array, by each time I'm storing one by one item.. meaning i don't need to store the whole array at one time.

Comment: You mean you update the array repeatedly and only want to store the difference? You can't, store the whole array each time.

Comment: Yes exactly, thats why I'm using indexPath.row .. any possible way ?

Comment: Only by storing each item in a different key in user defaults - just save the whole array each time

Answer (score 0):

NSArray do not store information about the types of objects contained in them. If you know for sure the types of objects in your array, you can perform a cast, either implicitly or explicitly:

```
NSString *n = [arr objectAtIndex:1];  // implicit type conversion (coercion) from id to NSString*
NSString *n = (NSString *)[arr objectAtIndex:1];  // explicit cast
```